# GTK#3 - Cannot get the revealer to work

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk3, gtk#

I have not been able to get the GTK Revealer to work properly. First off, I am using GTK3.12, and C#.

I currently have a expander which works fine, but I want to use a revealer instead for the animation. The issue is, I cannot get it to expand.

```
    bin revealTest = new bin (_builder.GetObject ("revPlayerStat").Handle);
    revealTest.Expand = true
```

Pretty much does nothing for me. I cannot seem to get GTK.Revealer so I have to use GTK.Bin since I presume that is the closest to it. (Widget might work too).

Answer (score 0):

To make the reaveler to work fine use this code

> revealTest.RevealChild = true

instead of

> revealTest.Expand = true

beacause the Expand command makes it to request more space instead of showing it's content and playing annimation